# sql запрос и вывод уникальных записей

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Здравствуйте.Имеется БД со структурой:

1. id
2. name
3. data_id

где data_id может быть одинаковой величиной.Имеем данные:

1. 1,запись 1, 1
2. 2,запись 2, 5
3. 3,запись 3, 1
4. 4,запись 4, 8
5. 5,запись 5, 1
6. 6,запись 6, 1

Нужно что составить запрос что бы получить такие данные:

1. 1,запись 1, 1
2. 2,запись 2, 5
3. 4,запись 4, 8

Как составить такой запрос?

Comment: иключить из выборки повторяющиеся data_id?

Comment: You can get last as simple as `SELECT * FROM t1 group by data_id`

Answer (score 2):

Если неважно какую именно строку нужно получить с каждым data_id, следующий запрос выдаст последнюю для каждого:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 group by data_id
```

Можно добавить постусловие `HAVING` чтобы определиться с этим:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 group by data_id having min(id)
```

[Fiddle](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5898211bbf7e88fa5d418b4f421a4bef128858ad4837d60455)

Comment: Оригинальная работа `having max(id)` в sqlite однако ... эта особенность где то в доке описана ?

Comment: Думаю, это shorthand для `having id = min(id)`, который уже не выглядит столь оригинальным) В доке не видел)

Comment: Из всех известных мне СУБД select * при наличии group by дал бы ошибку. Исключения MySQL и SQLite. И в MySQL having id=max(id) не работает. Так что это очень красивая особенность SQLIte

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from myTable where id in (select min(id) from myTable group by data_id)
```

[пример на sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd357/1)

Comment: Этот ответ более масштабируем. Лучше использовать его, если вы когда-нибудь планируете менять хранилище.